# How to pass templated ints to a template class?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

Let's say I have this:

```
template<int W, int H>
struct A
{
    A()
    {
        std::cout << W << " - " << H << std::endl;
    }
};
```

And I also have another struct that need the `A` struct:

```
template<template<int W, int H> typename A>
struct B
{
    B()
    {
        std::cout << W << " - " << H << std::endl;
    }
};
```

My question is, how can I instantiate `B`? At what point should I provide the `int`'s?

```
int main()
{
    B<A<50, 50>> b; // "A<50, 50>" is not a template class
    return 0;
}
```

Is there something wrong on my template-to-template declaration on the `B` struct?

Comment: Is `B` only supposed to accept `A`s?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't work the way you think. When you write,

```
template<template<int W, int H> typename A>
struct B
```

, that `A` has nothing to do with the `template<int, int> struct A` you've defined before (similarly to that a local variable hides the global in it's scope). The definition you gave expects a *template class* (e.g., `A`, but without arguments), thus `W` and `H` won't be available inside. In fact, we usually don't write the name of those arguments to signify this, but that's just a convention.

If you wanted to take a concrete `A<W, H>`, then perhaps the best thing you can do is specialize for this:

```
template<typename A_>
struct B;

template<int W, int H>
struct B<A<W, H>>
{
    // current body of class B
}
```

Then your code will work. Another possibility is to provide (`constexpr`) getters for `W` and `H` in `A`, but even then you need to take a concrete class in `B`'s definition.

Answer (score 1):

One more way to do it is to define W an H as constants inside A class.

```
template<int W_, int H_>
struct A
{
    static const int W = W_;
    static const int H = H_;
    A()
    {
        std::cout << W << " - " << H << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct B
{
    B()
    {
        std::cout << T::W << " - " << T::H << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B<A<50, 50>> b;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to supply any type with two `int`s as template parameters, you could make a specialization:

```cpp
template <class> struct B; // primary template

// specialization for any `T<int, int>`, such as `A<50, 50>`:
template <template <int, int> class T, int W, int H>
struct B<T<W, H>> {
    B() {
        std::cout << W << " - " << H << std::endl; 
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rxoqK5Yja)

If you only want to accept `A`s, then [lorros answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75716359/7582247) shows how to do that.